# How to set nonstandard attribute in html using javascript

Tags: javascript

According to a book I read there are two ways to do it. Which are as follows:

First way

```
var insTag = document.body.getElementsByTagName('ins');
for(var i = 0;i < insTag.length; i++){
 insTag[i].setAttribute('chord', 'value');
}
```

Second way

```
var insTag = document.querySelector('ins');
insTag.setAttribute('chord', 'value');
```

And this is the code in the html file:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script src='./index.js'></script>
  <script src='https://www.scales-chords.com/api/scales-chords-api.js'></script>

  <ins class='scales_chords_api'></ins>
 </body
</html>
```

The ins tag has an attribute called 'chord' which I'd like to set through the JavaScript file.

The above code doesn't seem to be setting the attribute and I'm getting no errors.

If I manually set the attibute in the html file everything works as expected.

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and html, and very confused as to how to sort this one out.

Thanks in advance for any help towards the solution.

Comment: If you run the code as is, you'll see an error in your browser **developer** tools console - this should be your first debugging step every time - once fixed, your code will do as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the scripts **after** the `ins` tag. The document loads from top to bottom; the tag needs to exist first before a script can do anything with it.

In general practice, scripts should be placed at the very bottom, right before `</body>`.

```html
<body>
  <ins class='scales_chords_api'></ins>
  ...
  <script>
    const insTag = document.querySelector('ins');
    insTag.setAttribute('chord', 'b');
  </script>
  <script src='https://www.scales-chords.com/api/scales-chords-api.js'></script>
</body>
```

In the snippet above I added the JS code directly in the HTML, but adding it in your `index.js` file is fine too. As long as you load that first, followed by the API.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I have actually tried your suggestion before, sorry for not mentioning it in the question. I think the reason why this approach is not working is because the api doesn't recognize the attribute 'data-chord'. It expects 'chord' instead. But this is just a thought that occured to me.

Comment: I figured it out, rewrote my answer completely with working code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your scripts after dom. Because there was no element before your code ran

[snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDSbH.png)

```
[code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4kujx8t/)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in trying to help. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? It seems to be working for me.

```js
var insTag = document.querySelector('ins');
insTag.setAttribute('chord', '4');

var insTagA = document.body.getElementsByTagName('insA');
for(var i = 0;i < insTagA.length; i++){
 insTagA[i].setAttribute('chordA', 'value');
}


console.log(insTag.getAttribute('chord'));
console.log(insTagA[0].getAttribute('chordA'));

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelector('ins');
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.attributes.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + x.attributes[i].name + " = " + x.attributes[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <script src='./index.js'></script>
  <script src='https://www.scales-chords.com/api/scales-chords-api.js'></script>

  <ins class='scales_chords_api'></ins>
  <insA class='scales_chords_api'></insA>
   <br/><br/>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

   <p id="demo"></p>
 </body
</html>
```

Comment: That's weird. What browser are you using? If I put the script tag before the ins tag, like you doing, it doesn't work here. I have tried both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I used firefox Quantum 63.0.1. No errors in console.
Checked Chrome. Works there as well.